# Install a pfx certificate in a users store in Windows using WiX

Tags: installation, wix, certificate, pfx

Please, can someone provide me with a WiX snippet or solution for the mentioned scenario. I need to include the pfx file in the WiX msi and the user will download my msi to his machine via the internet explorer and Click install and I need also the certificate to be installed on his machine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need the [Certificate element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/iis_xsd_certificate.htm). It is part of the IIS extension for wix, but can be used for non-IIS related installations also.

You need to

1. declare a prefix for the iis namespace, for
   example like this in the root Wix element:

   ```
   <Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'
      xmlns:iis='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension'>
   ```
2. Embed the PFX file as a binary
   stream in your install package. Add
   a [Binary](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_binary.htm) element under the
   product element like this:

   ```
   <Binary Id="MyCertificateBinaryStream" 
      SourceFile="c:/path/to/mycertificate.pfx" />
   ```
3. Declare a component with a `<iis:Certificate>` element, for
   example like this. Look at the
   [documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/iis_xsd_certificate.htm), you need to fill in some
   more attributes. Note that you don't need `CertficatePath` if you use the `BinaryKey` attribute.

   ```
   <Component Id="MyCertificateComponent" Guid="MY-GUID-HERE">
      <iis:Certificate Id="MyCertificate"
         BinaryKey="MyCertificateBinaryStream"
         ... some more attributes ...                  
      />
   </Component>
   ```
4. Activate the IIS extension by adding
   the option `-ext WixIISExtension`
   option when invoking the wix command line tools. If you use visual studio, this is just a matter of adding a reference in your wix project to `WixIISExtension`.

Comment: I will look into this answer and try.Thank you for your answer again.Really appreciate your explanation.A merry Christmas to you!

Answer (score 6):

To expand on the answer a little, the following set of attributes worked for me:

```
<iis:Certificate 
    Id="My.Certificate" 
    StoreName="root" 
    Overwrite="yes" 
    Name="My Friendly Certificate Name" 
    Request="no" 
    BinaryKey="MyCertificate.Binary" 
    StoreLocation="localMachine" />
```

Where the `<Product>` element contained a `<Binary>` child as follows:

```
<Binary 
    Id="MyCertificate.Binary" 
    SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)MyCertificate.pfx" />
```

(I included the PFX file within my WiX project).

Comment: For some reason, with this code, Wix does not install the cert in the user's store.  It ends up in IIS for some crazy reason, and is not usable by my application.  Changing the PFX to a PEM file DOES put it in the user's store, but it's missing the private key! So also not usable. Very strange.