# Private key missing when cert installed on Windows machine using WiX installer

Tags: windows, wix, ssl-certificate, pfx, netsh

I need to install a cert to allow a browser to talk to localhost via our app.  The .pfx file created for this purpose works great when imported with the Windows 10 MMC tool.  But that's a lot of steps to make our users do manually.

By following the steps in this answer ([Install a pfx certificate in a users store in Windows using WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957432/install-a-pfx-certificate-in-a-users-store-in-windows-using-wix)), I can build an MSI and it runs on the target machine without errors.

However, the cert does not exist in the usual "Certificates - Local Computer" MMC tool, nor can the cert be bound to the app with `netsh`.  After a bit of searching, it turns out the cert is installed "somewhere in IIS", and is only visible in the IIS tool (?!).

Using `openssl`, I converted the .pfx to a .pem file.  When running the MSI, this DOES seem to install the cert to the proper place (?!).  However, the cert is missing the private key, so it also can't be bound with `netsh` ('SSL Certificate add failed, Error 1312').

What on earth is going on, and how can I make Wix install the certificate properly?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess I figured it out.  I tried running the MSI on a virgin Windows 10 installation, and the .pfx file installed correctly and can be bound ok.

So, my guess is that "something" is checking the local computer to see if IIS is installed, and makes the decision to install the cert in a place that only IIS can see or use it.  There's probably a lot more going on behind the scenes, but that's the gist of it.

In summary, use a .pfx file to get the private key, and remember that the installation will only work on computers without IIS installed.